# Looping throuch complex objects in YAML

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an object that I am passing as a parameter like so

```
keyVaults:
      test-az-kv-01:
        - filter: clientID
        - second: test
      test-az-kv-02:
        - filter: clientID2
        - second: wonderful
```

And what I would like to do is execute steps in my pipeline template based on this object

```
- ${{ each kv in parameters.keyVaults }}:
   - script: echo '${{ kv.key }} - ${{ kv.filter }}''
           displayName: Test outer
```

So kv.key is obviously working but I would like to access the filter and second values for both keyvault items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my life easier, I did the following:

parameter structure:

```
keyVaults:
      - name: test-az-kv-01
        filter: clientID
        second: test
      - name: test-az-kv-02
        filter: clientID2
        second: wonderful
```

and then the code:

```
- ${{ each kv in parameters.keyVaults }}:
   - script: echo '${{ kv.name }} - ${{ kv.filter }}'
     displayName: Test outer
```

This ended fixed my issue!